# Ruby & Rails - Convert String to Proc

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I'm in the following situation. The current url looks like the following:

`/categories/Art`

And I'm using `name = location.pathname.split('/')[2]` in order to grab the `Art` portion of the URL. Then, I send an AJAX the following path back to the controller: `http://localhost:3000/sort?sortMethod=name&category=name` or date, whichever link is clicked on.

Now in my controller I can use `sort = params[:category]` to get the string `name`, yet what I'd like to do with this string is sort an array by it. `@categories` is an array of objects and I'd like to call `.sort_by(&:sort)` yet it doesn't recognize the string value of `sort = name`. So now I'd like to convert this string into a proc in order to sort the array. Anyone know how I accomplish this?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert it to a symbol first and then use Symbol#to_proc:

```
@categories.sort_by(&sort.to_sym)
```

However be sure that the users can't call anything malicious on your objects like:

```
http://localhost:3000/sort?sortMethod=destroy
```

One way of protecting yourself is to use [`attribute_accessible`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveModel/MassAssignmentSecurity/ClassMethods/attr_accessible) definitions in your model and then do

```
@categories.sort_by(&sort.to_sym) if Category.accessible_attributes.include? sort.to_sym
```

Comment: How would you recommend I go about protecting myself from that? What are some common approaches to a similar situation?

Comment: Have a list of whitelisted methods. Do some like this: sort_by(&sort.to_sym) if whitelist.include?(sort)

Comment: I've added an example specific for ActiveRecord, but you can have a whitelist for any object.

Comment: Fyi, this method opens you up to a specific kind of DOS attack: http://www.tricksonrails.com/2010/06/avoid-memory-leaks-in-ruby-rails-code-and-protect-against-denial-of-service/

You may want to consider checking whether the attribute is accessible BEFORE converting the user input to a symbol.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not entirely clear, so you may need to adjust the following solution. However, the basic idea is taht it's possible to do something like:

```
Category.all.sort_by {|category| category.method(params[:category]).call }
```

Comment: While I was writing also Jakub answered. I think both solutions work; his solution is a shorthand to this one and could be preferred. Use mine if you need to be a little more flexible, e.g. if you want to handle errors whenever `params[:category]` contains a string that is not an instance method of `Category` (what happens if a user requests `...?sortMethod=a_method_that_does_not_exist` or `...?sortMethod=destroy`?)

Answer (score 0):

Also, the "Art" portion of your url is available in Rails' params hash as params[:action], so you don't have to do location.pathname.split('/')[2].

Comment: I need to grab it in the javascript function, not the rails controller.